# Linq xml nested query with c#

Tags: c#, xml

So far I can display the

```
<group number=
```

and

```
<category number=
```

How can i display

`<category label=` attributes for each category?

### Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<outputTree xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/xml/oms" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/xml/oms http://www.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/xml/oms/spss-output-1.8.xsd">
  <command command="Summarize" displayOutlineValues="label" displayOutlineVariables="label" displayTableValues="label" displayTableVariables="label" lang="en" text="Summarize">
    <pivotTable subType="Report" text="Batch Processing Report">
      <dimension axis="row" text="Cases">
        <group label="Test Site" text="Test Site" varName="PLANT_DESC" variable="true">
          <group hide="true" text="A">
            <group string="A" text="AA" varName="PLANT_DESC">
              <group label="Product" text="Product" varName="PROD_DESC" variable="true">
                <group hide="true" text="A">
                  <group string="S" text="S" varName="PROD_DESC">
                    <group label="Batch Number" text="Batch Number" varName="BATCH_NO" variable="true">
                      <group hide="true" text="A">
                        <group number="3704542" text="3704542" varName="BATCH_NO">
                          <category number="1" text="1">
                            <dimension axis="column" text="Variables">
                              <category label="Batch Run" text="Batch Run" varName="BATCH_RUN_ID" variable="true">
                                <cell number="4202" text="4202" varName="BATCH_RUN_ID"/>
                              </category>
                              <category label="Application" text="Application" varName="APP_ID" variable="true">
                                <cell label="Calibration" number="101" text="Calibration" varName="APP_ID"/>
                              </category>
                            </dimension>
                          </category>
                          <category number="2" text="2">
                            <dimension axis="column" text="Variables">
                              <category label="Batch Run" text="Batch Run" varName="BATCH_RUN_ID" variable="true">
                                <cell number="4341" text="4341" varName="BATCH_RUN_ID"/>
                              </category>
                              <category label="Application" text="Application" varName="APP_ID" variable="true">
                                <cell label="Range Setting" number="201" text="Range Setting" varName="APP_ID"/>
                              </category>
                            </dimension>
                          </category>
                        </group>
                      </group>
                    </group>
                  </group>
                </group>
              </group>
            </group>
          </group>
        </group>
      </dimension>
    </pivotTable>
  </command>
</outputTree>
```

### C

```
private void GetXMLData1()
{
    try
    {
        XNamespace ns = "http://www.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/xml/oms";
        XDocument testXML = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\byilmaz\Desktop\SPSS_SITE\test.xml");

        var cats = from cat in testXML.Descendants(ns + "dimension").Where
                   (cat => (string)cat.Attribute("axis") == "column" && (string)cat.Attribute("text") == "Variables")

                   select new
                       {
                           BATCH_NO = cat.Parent.Parent.Attribute("number").Value,
                           RUN_NO = cat.Parent.Attribute("number").Value,                                   
                       }
                       ;

        foreach (var cat in cats)
        {
            //xmlTitle.Text += "Group Name: " + cat.groupName + " and Cat Id: " + cat.catId + " and Cat Name: " + cat.catName + " and Cat Cell: " + cat.catCell + "</br>";

            xmlTitle.Text += "BATCH_NO: " + cat.BATCH_NO + " </br>";
            xmlTitle.Text += "RUN_NO: " + cat.RUN_NO + " </br><hr>";
        }

    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        throw (err);
    }
}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `Descendants()` at the beginning, why not use them for the categories too?

```
select new
         {
             BATCH_NO = cat.Parent.Parent.Attribute("number").Value,
             RUN_NO = cat.Parent.Attribute("number").Value,
             InnerCategories = cat.Descendants(ns + "category").Select(c => c.Attribute("label").Value)
         };
```

and then in the foreach loop you have:

```
foreach (var cat in cats)
{
   //xmlTitle.Text += "Group Name: " + cat.groupName + " and Cat Id: " + cat.catId + " and Cat Name: " + cat.catName + " and Cat Cell: " + cat.catCell + "</br>";

     xmlTitle.Text += "BATCH_NO: " + cat.BATCH_NO + " </br>";
     xmlTitle.Text += "RUN_NO: " + cat.RUN_NO + " </br><hr>";


     foreach (string s in cat.InnerCategories )
     {
        // process them one by one 
     }

     // or print them at once

     string joinedInnerCats = string.Join(",", cat.InnerCategories);
     xmlTitle.Text += string.Format("Categories: {0}", joinedInnerCats);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks alot Rosen, how do i do the inner foreach loop? can you show me any example?

Comment: I updated my post. In the context of your usage, I guess you will have to use them where you display the Batch No and Run No maybe?

Comment: i mean how will i get the value in the inner loop?

Comment: string s (defined in the loop) represents the value of the current category in the loop. cat.InnerCategories will contain 2 items - strings "Batch Run" and "Application" in your example (the values of the label attribute).

Comment: Thanks alot, i will check it tomorrow.